# Scala - How to get the Max value of a Json field?

Tags: json, regex, scala

I'm trying to get the maximum value of a MetricId field from a JSON String. However I'm getting a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max` for the below String:

```
[{"MetricName":"name1","DateParsed":"2019-11-20 05:39:00","MetricId":"7855","isValid":"true"},
{"MetricName":"name2","DateParsed":"2019-05-22 17:45:00","MetricId":"1295","isValid":"false"}]
```

Here is how I've implemented a method for finding the Max value:

```
val metricIdRegex = """"MetricId"\s*:\s*(\d+)""".r

def maxMetricId(jsonString: String): String = {
  metricIdRegex.findAllIn(jsonString).map({
    case metricIdRegex(id) => id.toInt
  }).max.toString
}

val maxId: String = maxMetricId(metricsString)
```

I'm expecting to get "7855" as a Max metric Id

What could be wrong with the method? I suspect that it could be a problem with the regex.

Comment: I think you have to add another `"` to the pattern `MetricId"\s*:\s*"(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/uJVVVh/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird tried your suggection but it didn't work

Comment: Is this not the expected? https://ideone.com/o7ylnB

Comment: Exactly, it worked. That was my bad, made a small typo. Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps you might look into using a json parser instead of a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use [json4s](http://queirozf.com/entries/json4s-examples-common-basic-operations-using-jackson-as-backend) which is quite popular and used by many other scala libraries:

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

val data = """[{"MetricName":"name1","DateParsed":"2019-11-20 05:39:00","MetricId":"7855","isValid":"true"},
{"MetricName":"name2","DateParsed":"2019-05-22 17:45:00","MetricId":"1295","isValid":"false"}]"""

// parse data into JValue
val parsed = parse(data)

// go through the parsed variable and extract MetricId into a string list, then cast every item to int
val maxMetricId = (parsed \ "MetricId" \\ classOf[JString]).map{_.toInt}.max
```

Comment: BEWARE: [Json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 1):

Let me show an example how it can be done with a JSON parser efficiently without holding of a whole JSON input and parsed data in memory.

Add dependencies to your `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-core"   % "2.0.2" % Compile,
  "com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter-scala" %% "jsoniter-scala-macros" % "2.0.2" % Provided // required only in compile-time
)
```

Add imports, define a data structure for repeating part of your JSON array which should be parsed out, derive a codec for it, open an input stream and scan it with provided handling function which will reduce all parsed metrics to the maximum value:

```
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros._
import com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.core._
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.InputStream

case class Metric(@stringified MetricId: Int)

implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Metric] = JsonCodecMaker.make(CodecMakerConfig)

val in: InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( // <- replace it by FileInputStream
  """[{"MetricName":"name1","DateParsed":"2019-11-20 05:39:00","MetricId":"7855","isValid":"true"},
      {"MetricName":"name2","DateParsed":"2019-05-22 17:45:00","MetricId":"1295","isValid":"false"}]""".getBytes("UTF-8"))

try {
  var max = -1
  scanJsonArrayFromStream[Metric](in) { m: Metric =>
    max = Math.max(max, m.MetricId)
    true
  }
  println(max)
} finally in.close()
```

And this code should print `7855`.

Comment: Note that this is not an unbiased answer, it is self-promotion of the author's own solution. There are other JSON parsers that are more widely used with better support and documentation.